# Allow JSON fragments with Decodable

Tags: json, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    //@IBOutlet weak var ingredientText: UILabel!

    struct Recipes: Decodable {
        let recipe_id:String?
        let image_url:String?
        let source_url:String?
        let f2f_url:String?
        let title:String?
        let publisher:String?
        let social_rank:Float64?
        let page:Int?
        let ingredients:[String]?

        private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
            case recipe_id = "recipe_id"
            case image_url = "image_url"
            case source_url = "source_url"
            case f2f_url = "f2f_url"
            case title = "title"
            case publisher = "publisher"
            case social_rank = "social_rank"
            case page = "page"
            case ingredients = "ingredients"
        }
    }

    var recipes = [Recipes]()
    var food = "chicken"
    var food2 = "peas"
    var food3 = "onions"
    //var recipeData = [Recipe]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    fileprivate func getRecipes() {
        let jsonURL = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=264045e3ff7b84ee346eb20e1642d9d9264045e3ff7b84ee346eb20e1642d9d9&food=chicken&food2=onions&food3=peas"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonURL) else{return}

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, _ , err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let err = err{
                    print("failed to get data from URL",err)
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else{return}

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    self.recipes = try decoder.decode([Recipes].self, from: data)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }catch let jsonERR {
                    print("Failed to decode",jsonERR)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return recipes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        let recipe = recipes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = recipe.title
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.title = "Ingredients"
        getRecipes()
    }
}
```

I am getting the error:

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Comment: Your URL gives 403 FORBIDDEN Error..... check status code....

Comment: Thanks Vishal.  The wrong API key was given in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSONDecoder` doesn't provide any `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions`.

You could make a *manual* check whether the first byte of the data is an opening square bracket `<5b>` or brace `<7b>`

```
guard let data = data, let firstByte = data.first else { return }
guard firstByte == 0x5b || firstByte == 0x7b else { 
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(string)
    return 
}
```

However I'd recommend to use the `response` parameter to check for status code 200

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response , error) in
    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode != 200 {
        print(response.statusCode)
        return
    }
...
```

Note: If the CodingKeys match exactly the struct members you can omit the CodingKeys and as you are explicitly using `.convertFromSnakeCase` you are encouraged to name the struct members `recipeId`, `imageUrl`, `sourceUrl` etc.

Comment: Vadian, Thank you for your answer that did help a lot.  I used your response perameter and did get the error 403, but I changed my API key and the error changed to, Failed to decode typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: If the root object is a dictionary you have to decode `Recipes.self`

Comment: The root object is a dictionary.  Will I have to make a separate struct for the root?  I am very new to swift and coding in general.  I changed the [Recipes].self to Recipes.self and am now getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: In terms of `Decodable` every dictionary is a struct. So you need an extra struct for the root object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to decode `[Recipe]`, that is, an `Array` of `Recipe`. That mean the first (non-whitespace) character in `data` has to be `[` (to make it a JSON array), and it's not. So you need to figure out why you're getting the wrong response, and fix that problem. Try converting `data` to a `String` and printing it:

```
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
```

Comment: I did that and it works.  I get The top 30 recipes from food2fork api.  However when I go to change the data to a string my self.recipes = try decoder.decode([Recipes].self, from: data) does not accept data as a string.  Trying to look now but this was also a good point.  Thank you.  If you know of a post to fix this please link.