# Using JSON Decodable in Swift 4.1

Tags: json, swift

```
{  
    "count":30,
    "recipes":[  
        {  
            "publisher":"Closet Cooking",
            "f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/35382",
            "title":"Jalapeno Popper Grilled Cheese Sandwich",
            "source_url":"http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/04/jalapeno-popper-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
            "recipe_id":"35382",
            "image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg",
            "social_rank":100.0,
            "publisher_url":"http://closetcooking.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I parse this JSON using Swift 4.1 Decodable please?

Comment: Downvoted because 1) Not [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) 2) No attempts shown.

Comment: Try https://app.quicktype.io/, on providing a valid json you will get the models here.

Comment: Although there are **M A N Y** posts related to this topic, I'd assume that you tried something before asking...  Would you show us :)

Comment: I'll make sure to show attempts next time. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Jonathan: you may be able to recover some of your score by making a retrospective attempt of your own and editing that into your question. It surely would not be pointless to do so, since it will give you practice - useful if you are unfamiliar with this language!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53274397/allow-json-fragments-with-decodable) is quite close but you have to add the struct for the root object

Declare the struct members non-optional as much as possible. The URLs can be decoded as `URL`

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let count : Int 
    let recipes : [Recipe]
}

struct Recipe : Decodable { // It's highly recommended to declare Recipe in singular form
    let recipeId : String
    let imageUrl, sourceUrl, f2fUrl : URL
    let title : String
    let publisher : String
    let socialRank : Double
    let page : Int?
    let ingredients : [String]?
}
```

Now decode

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
self.recipes = result.recipes
```

Comment: I did exactly as you described, but I am still getting an error. Failed to decode keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "f2FURL", intValue: nil),  @vadian

Comment: and also [CodingKeys(stringValue: "recipes", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription:

Comment: Case sensitivity matters: It's `f2fUrl` And what is the *message* of the second error?

Answer (score -1):

below are the models for your JSON:

```
struct Recipe: Codable{
    let publisher: String
    let f2f_url: String
    let title: String
    let source_url: String
    let recipe_id: String
    let image_url: String
    let social_rank: Float
    let publisher_url: String
}


struct  Model: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let recipes: [Recipe]
}
```

and below is JSON decodable:

```
let json = """
{
    "count":30,
    "recipes":[
        {
            "publisher":"Closet Cooking",
            "f2f_url":"http://food2fork.com/view/35382",
            "title":"Jalapeno Popper Grilled Cheese Sandwich",
            "source_url":"http://www.closetcooking.com/2011/04/jalapeno-popper-grilled-cheese-sandwich.html",
            "recipe_id":"35382",
            "image_url":"http://static.food2fork.com/Jalapeno2BPopper2BGrilled2BCheese2BSandwich2B12B500fd186186.jpg",
            "social_rank":100.0,
            "publisher_url":"http://closetcooking.com"
        }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
   let model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: json) //Decode JSON Response Data
   print(model)
} catch let parsingError {
   print("Error", parsingError)
}
```

Comment: We don't usually use the *snake case* when naming variables in Swift, so you might need to do something about it :)